# SQL Server: Sql query to find the list of the servers where the login is present

Tags: sql-server, logins

How to find the list of the servers where the login is present(other than registered servers)

Comment: You want to check an unknown number of servers which you may or may not have all the names for, for a specific logon? If it's a SQL Authentication account, they could have different passwords on each server. Would you count this as the "same"?

Comment: I need to know the server names where login resides on

Comment: You will need to user PowerShell or something similar to loop through a list of servers and run `select @@SERVERNAME, name from sys.server_principals where name = 'SomeUser'` on each server.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you want to know if a login exists on instances that you know of, then  [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) can work.

By using the command [Get-DbaLogin](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Get-DbaLogin)

**Finding if a login exists on one instance**

```
Get-DbaLogin -SqlInstance InstanceName -Login LoginName
```

**Finding if a login exists on multiple instances**

```
'InstanceName1', 'InstanceName2' | Get-DbaLogin -Login LoginName
```

**Sample output of the second command**

```
ComputerName : Computer1
InstanceName : MSSQLSERVER
SqlInstance  : Computer1
Name         : Domain\LoginName
LoginType    : WindowsUser
CreateDate   : 23/04/2018 11:27:41
LastLogin    : 
HasAccess    : True
IsLocked     : 
IsDisabled   : False

ComputerName : Computer2
InstanceName : MSSQLSERVER
SqlInstance  : Computer2
Name         : Domain\LoginName
LoginType    : WindowsUser
CreateDate   : 6/02/2018 11:21:54
LastLogin    : 
HasAccess    : True
IsLocked     : 
IsDisabled   : False
```